# ionic: error adding android and building the apk

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 project that I upgraded to ionic 4, because ionic asked me to do so. I just upgraded the cli. Everything was working before I upgraded ionic, I built many apks successfully

I tried with different android versions. When I try android

```
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.0.0
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms\android
    Package: com.test.jokerleb
    Name: jokerleb
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-26
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Android project created with cordova-android@7.0.0
Android Studio project detected
Android Studio project detected
Installing "cordova-plugin-camera" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-compat@1.2.0" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.0.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-compat" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 7.0.0, failed version requirement: 
      <6.3.0
Skipping 'cordova-plugin-compat' for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-facebook4" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for android
Plugin dependency "es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "es6-promise-plugin" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android
installing external dependencies via npm
npm install of external dependencies ok
Dependent plugin "es6-promise-plugin" already installed on android.
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'ionic-plugin-keyboard': CordovaError: Uh oh!
"C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\src\main\java\io\ionic\keyboard\IonicKeyboard.java" already exists!
    at copyNewFile (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\lib\pluginHandlers.js:261:45)
    at install (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\lib\pluginHandlers.js:51:17)
    at ActionStack.process (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ActionStack.js:56:25)
    at PluginManager.doOperation (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:114:20)
    at PluginManager.addPlugin (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\PluginManager.js:144:17)
    at C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:247:74
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
    at C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:570:49
```

And `cordova build --release android`

```
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb>cordova build --release android
Android Studio project detected
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Android\android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172
studio
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_4jy5safns4ahg2gipcl84q3ka.run(C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:143)
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:platformAttrExtractor UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:javaPreCompileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes NO-SOURCE
:CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease UP-TO-DATE
:app:processReleaseResourcesC:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:52: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_id) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:59: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_id) not found.
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:55: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:59: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Failed to execute aapt
 FAILED
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
25 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 24 up-to-date
(node:11064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:52: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_id) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:55: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:59: AAPT: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.

C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:52: error: resource string/fb_app_id (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_id) not found.
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:55: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.
C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\release\AndroidManifest.xml:59: error: resource string/fb_app_name (aka com.test.jokerleb:string/fb_app_name) not found.
error: failed processing manifest.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:454)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:411)
        at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
        at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\user-pc\Desktop\jokerleb\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:11064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11064) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "jokerleb",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "author": "Lynob",
    "homepage": "http://lynob.com",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
        "@ionic-native/camera": "4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/core": "4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.10.1",
        "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.10.0",
        "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.8.0",
        "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.8.0",
        "@ionic/pro": "1.0.20",
        "@ionic/storage": "^2.1.3",
        "cordova-android": "^7.0.0",
        "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
        "cordova-plugin-compat": "1.2.0",
        "cordova-plugin-device": "2.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
        "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
        "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3",
        "intl-tel-input": "12.4.0",
        "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
        "ionic-img-viewer": "2.9.0",
        "ionicons": "3.0.0",
        "jquery": "3.3.1",
        "rxjs": "5.5.11",
        "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
        "zone.js": "0.8.26"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
        "typescript": "~2.6.2"
    },
    "description": "An Ionic project",
    "cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears to be 2 different versions of the Ionic Keyboard plugin:

```
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Installing "ionic-plugin-keyboard" for android
```

[ionic-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-keyboard) is deprecated in favour of [cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard) so remove it:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm ionic-plugin-keyboard
```

Comment: I removed it, `cordova build --release android` error is still there, are they related?

Comment: you may need to remove and re-add the platform to apply changes: `cordova platform rm android --nosave && cordova platform add android --nosave`. Also check the `ionic-plugin-keyboard` directory has actually been removed from `plugins/`.

Comment: when i add android, the keyboard automatically gets added